# UIImageView.center not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

Wondering why my code isn't working? Giving me an error:

> Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'CenterSmallDot'

Trying to get it so when the WhiteDot is dragged and touches the SmallDot center it prints "It Worked."

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var CenterSmallDot = SmallDot.center
}

@IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)

    if let view = recognizer.view {
        view.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x + translation.x, y: view.center.y + translation.y)
    }

    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)

    if (WhiteDot.frame.intersects(SmallDot.CenterSmallDot)) {
        print("It Worked")
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Change `if (WhiteDot.frame.intersects(SmallDot.CenterSmallDot)) {` to `if (WhiteDot.frame.intersects(SmallDot.center)) {`.

Comment: I tried that, but it gives error "Cannot convert value of type 'CGPoint' to expected argument type 'CGRect.'

Comment: Of course. Also change `intersects` to `contains`.

Comment: Thank you, you have helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, `WhiteDot` and `SmallDot` are both `UIImageView`.
The `CenterSmallDot` is a local variable in the `viewDidLoad` func of your viewController, so you can't use it anywhere outside the `viewDidLoad` func.
A quick fix would be to drop the `CenterSmallDot`variable

```
if (WhiteDot.frame.intersects(SmallDot.center)) {
        print("It Worked")
    }
```

Now you'll have another issue: the `intersects` takes a `CGRect` parameter, not a `CGPoint`. Just use the `contains` method instead:

```
if (WhiteDot.frame.contains(SmallDot.center)) {
            print("It Worked")
        }
```

As you seems to begin with Swift, here is a great book from Apple:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-3-1/id881256329?mt=11

You'll learn a lot about - in our case- variables and naming convention, and more generally about how Swift is working.

Comment: I tried that before this and gave error  "Cannot convert value of type 'CGPoint' to expected argument type 'CGRect.' That is why I was trying to use a variable instead of .center